# Can I travel to the UK unaccompanied on an accompanied child visa now that I am over 18?

Tags: visas, uk, children, solo-travel

I got a visa with my mother when I was 17 years old. On it was stated "Not valid unless accompanied by my mother".

Can I travel to the UK alone now that I am 18?

Comment: Don't you mean "only valid if accompanied" rather than "valid unless accompanied"? The way you've written it makes it look like you are not allowed to enter the UK if your mother is with you ...

Answer (score 4):

The controlling technical reference for this situation is spelled out in Paragraph 321 of the rules...

> 321. A person seeking leave to enter the United Kingdom who holds an entry clearance which was duly issued to him and is still current may
>        be refused leave to enter only where the Immigration Officer is
>        satisfied that:
>
>      ... not applicable stuff, then...
>
> (ii) a change of circumstances since it was issued has removed the
>   basis of the holder’s claim to admission, except where the change of
>   circumstances amounts solely to the person becoming over age for entry
>   in one of the categories contained in paragraphs 296-316 of these
>   Rules since the issue of the entry clearance;

The exceptions they refer to as listed in paragraphs 296 - 316 have to do with children admitted with a [view to settlement](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/children-set07/children-set07#set713-how-do-children-of-parentss-being-admitted-with-a-view-to-settlement-in-the-uk-qualify) (e.g., the child of a person admitted as a fiance or spouse) and now want to apply for permanent residence along with the primary and hence  **do not apply to you**.

And for port-side refusals, Paragraph 321A provides the reference...

> 321A. The following grounds for the cancellation of a person’s leave
>   to enter or remain which is in force on his arrival in, or whilst he
>   is outside, the United Kingdom apply;
>
> (1) there has been such a change in the circumstances of that person’s
>   case since the leave was given, that it should be cancelled;

So Paragraph 321 gives the Immigration Officer a [mandatory](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandatory) grounds for your removal.  The things listed in Paragraphs 320 and 321 are without discretionary latitude (i.e., the Immigration Officer has no choice in the matter).

**What all of this amalgamates to is: don't do it, you could find yourself in detention facing removal.**

Adding: in theory this *should be picked up by the carrier* who would then refuse boarding permission.

Comment: I read your answer 3 times now and I still don't think I understand it. What do "a view to settlement" and "discretionary latitude" even mean?

Comment: @J.Constantine It mean "No", I think. Could definitley be clearer for the sake of the OP though

Comment: What a useless question-begging piece of nonsense is 321A: it says that a person's leave to enter should be cancelled if circumstances have changed enough that the leave should be cancelled.

Comment: @phoog There are some examples in Macdonald's that help clarify any grey areas. It's reviewed by Phillip Taylor [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2sEB3c_ld0). The tomes are not cheap for a good reason!

Comment: None of this appears to have anything to do with the specific issue of accompanied visas or turning 18.

Comment: @NateEldredge: This might be asked on Law.SE, but the general principle here is that a narrow exception implies the non-existence of a broader exception. Specifically, "becoming over age" has a narrow exception (only paragraphs 296-316 ) and therefore "becoming over age" is not an exception in other situations. That means the general rule of 321 holds.