# Can my 20 years old child enter UK on her own with a C Visit Child Accompanied visa?

Tags: visas, children

As a family are all Turkish citizens and I got a 10 years multiple entry C Visit Child Accompanied visa when my daughter was 16 years old. Now she is 20 years old and studying in Amsterdam and she is a Dutch Resident. Me and my wife will go to London and our daughter would like to join us there, can she travel to the UK with this visa on her own as she is already over 18 or does she still need one of us to accompany her?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I travel to the UK unaccompanied on an accompanied child visa now that I am over 18?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68130/can-i-travel-to-the-uk-unaccompanied-on-an-accompanied-child-visa-now-that-i-am) The conclusion from this answer is *‘**No**,she cannot use the visa at all because there has been a material change of circumstances since the visa was issued’*